# How can I shorten this jQuery code?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, optimization

I'm checking out jQuery ui and while the code works how I want it to, I wonder if it could be shortened.
I've tried to do it myself but haven't been able to. I would appreciate any help on this.

How can I shorten this code?

```
JQUERY:

  $(function() {
      $("#accordion").accordion({
          collapsible: true,
          active: 'none'
      });
  });

  $(function() {
      var icons = {
          header: "ui-icon ui-icon-plus",
          activeHeader: "ui-icon ui-icon-minus"
      };
      $("#accordion").accordion({
          icons: icons
      });
      $("#toggle").button().on("click", function() {
          if ($("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons")) {
              $("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons", null);
          } else {
              $("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons", icons);
          }
      });
  });

  $("#tabs").tabs({
      disabled: [2, 3]
  });

  $("#tabs").tabs({
      hide: {
          effect: "drop",
          duration: 750
      }
  });

  $("#tabs").tabs({
      show: {
          effect: "drop",
          duration: 750
      }
  });

  $("#tabs").tabs({
      heightStyle: "auto"
  });
```

Comment: can you add the html code and the functionality of the code . its good to have a fiddle example

Comment: You only need to wrap your code in one `$(function(){});`. So there is one thing.

Comment: When you assign options for `.tabs()`, you're using the same selector, so the same elements, just put it all into one. Unless you're planning to make 3 different sets of tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are all the items I suggested in the comments:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ywx0yrub/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var icons = {
    header: "ui-icon ui-icon-plus",
    activeHeader: "ui-icon ui-icon-minus"
  };
  $("#accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: 'none',
    icons: icons
  });
  $("#toggle").button().click(function() {
    if ($("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons")) {
      $("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons", null);
    } else {
      $("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons", icons);
    }
  });
  $("#tabs").tabs({
    disabled: [2, 3],
    hide: {
      effect: "drop",
      duration: 750
    },
    show: {
      effect: "drop",
      duration: 750
    },
    heightStyle: "auto"
  });
});
```

1. Wrap all your code in one
2. Define all parts of your initialization in a single statement
3. Since your button is static, you do not need to use `.on()`. This is not wrong, yet you can make it shorter by just using `.click()`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful